# Optimization function returns the same optimal parameters for two labels

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, machine-learning-model, optimization, matlab

I've recently enrolled in the Coursera machine learning, and am working my way through making my own classifier for the [Iris dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/iris) problem using matlab. I'm training a classifier for each species (the one-vs-all method). The code runs smoothly without any errors, but the results are not quite what I was expecting. Here's my matlab code:

```
clear, clc

% loading the data
data = csvread('data.csv');

% extracting the features
X = data(:, (1:end-3));
X = [ones(size(X, 1), 1) X];

% computing the number of training examples (m) and features (n)
[m, n] = size(X);

% extracting the labels
y_setosa = data(:, end-2);
y_versicolor = data(:, end-1);
y_virginica = data(:, end);

% initializing the options for optimization algorithm
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 10);

% creating the initial theta vector
iniTheta = zeros(n, 1);

% tarining a classifier for each label
[theta_setosa, min_setosa] = fminunc(@(theta) costFunction(theta, m, X, y_setosa), iniTheta, options);
[theta_versicolor, min_versicolor] = fminunc(@(theta) costFunction(theta, m, X, y_versicolor), iniTheta, options);
[theta_virginica, min_virginica] = fminunc(@(theta) costFunction(theta, m, X, y_virginica), iniTheta, options);
```

Here's the code for my costFunction:

```
function [jValue, gradient] = costFunction(theta, m, X, Y)
    V = X*theta;
    jValue = (-1/m)*sum(Y.*log(sigmoid(V)) + (1-Y).*log(1-sigmoid(V)));
    gradient = (-1/m)*X'*(sigmoid(V)-Y);
end
```

And finally my sigmoid function:

```
function sigX = sigmoid(X)
    sigX = arrayfun(@(n) 1/(1+exp(-n)), X);
end
```

The resulting theta_setosa and theta_versicolor vectors are all zeros, and the costFunction has the same minumum for the both of them. the virginica classifier seems to be working fine however. Although for each fminunc I get the following message displayed

```
Local minimum possible.
fminunc stopped because it cannot decrease the objective function
along the current search direction.
<stopping criteria details>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error stemmed apparently from the formula for the gradient: there should be no minus sign (-) at the start of it. The correct code for this would be:

```
function [jValue, gradient] = costFunction(theta, m, X, Y)
    V = X*theta;
    jValue = (-1/m)*sum(Y.*log(sigmoid(V)) + (1-Y).*log(1-sigmoid(V)));
    gradient = (1/m)*X'*(sigmoid(V)-Y);
end
```